# How to use I18n to translate exceptions messages in jsf

Tags: java, jsf, exception

Is there any possibility to translate the exceptions thrown of validators in jsf? I mean, I have some classes which check if the input is right, if it is not, they will throw an exception with a message and the message will be displayed on the website. My question is if is it possible to use i18n to translate those exceptions messages.

Comment: @Seleron: do you actually vote to close as duplicate or type this in? I did not see your vote

Comment: I hit `flag` -> `a duplicate` -> Paste URL etc. @Kukeltje - and in my list of flags I see that this one here is already considered `helpful`. I need to do additional 700rep worth of contribution for beeing able to close/reopen vote :-D

Comment: ahhhh ok... Cheers... Lets get the 700 quick then ;-)

Comment: @Kukeltje But not too quick ^^ Weeks ago someone 'upvote-attacked' me and I suddenly had +80. Better like to earn it

Comment: I only added 20... not much more... But back then, it might have been me too ... otoh, no, not 80... I could  'give' you 665 of mine by adding a bounty on one of your answers ;-)... hahaha